# Unsure why logic will not turn game object active

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My logic has worked in the past, but it is unclear why this does not work to turn my gameobjects active. This is especially puzzling as I have no errors. The fields match up correctly and I have no errors as mentioned. This is used for an inventory system.

```
 public class addToArtMode : MonoBehaviour
{

    public bool On = true;
    public GameObject slotPanel;

    void Start()
    {
        this.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => AddToArtMode());
        slotPanel = GameObject.Find("Slot Panel");

    }

    public void AddToArtMode()
    {
        if (On)
        {
            Debug.Log("ID'ing ");
            slotPanel = GameObject.Find("Slot Panel");


            foreach (Transform child in slotPanel.transform)
            {
                var parentName = this.GetComponentInParent<ArtBrowseContentInformation>().NameofArt;
                var childname = child.GetComponent<InventoryContentInfo>().NameofArt;
                if (childname == parentName)
                {

                    child.gameObject.SetActive(true);
                    On = false;
                    Debug.Log("what ");
                }
                else
                {
                    Off();

                }
            }



            void Off()
            {
                foreach (Transform child in slotPanel.transform)
                {
                    var parentName = this.GetComponentInParent<ArtBrowseContentInformation>().NameofArt;
                    var childname = child.GetComponent<InventoryContentInfo>().NameofArt;
                    if (childname == parentName)
                    {
                        Debug.Log("the heck");
                        child.gameObject.SetActive(false);
                        On = true;

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Have you set breakpoint and check status? `childname == parentName` is a statement only you would know what your data are. No one could help. Unless you have specific data and you can't figure it out. If breakpoint is not allowed, print it to console could help.

Answer (score -1):

try gameObject.enabled = false/true;